# Позиция слов datagridview

Tags: c#, строки

нужна очень помощь, пожалуйста. В datagridview находится массив слов, который берется с richtextbox. Нужно чтобы по нажатию на конкретное слово в первом datagridview, в другой datagridview выводились позиции этого слова в тексте (n1, n2, n3, ..., nn), в третью колонку выводилось розница между первыми двумя позициями. Помогите, пожалуйста, очень нужно. 
[image: Вот картинка, как все выглядит]

Comment: А в чем проблема то?

Comment: Как пройтись по тексту и записывать позиции конкретного слова?

Comment: У строки есть метод IndexOf, попробуйте его

Answer (score 0):

```
  Попробуй вот это надеюсь поможет

private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {

                int index = 0;
                dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value; // передаем значение во 2ой грид 

                dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value = e.RowIndex; // передаем индекс во второй грид

            }
```

Comment: К сожалению не то. Но спасибо. Нужно чтобы выводилась каждая позиция слова. И во 2-й грид 3-ю колонку выводился результат N2-N1...

Answer (score 0):

[image: пример работы]

Если вы работаете не с базовыми типами, а собственными классами, то такой функционал очень просто реализовать через привязки.
Допустим, у вас есть такие классы

```
//для отображения позиций слова в тексте
public class WordPosition : IWordPosition
{
    public int Start { get; private set; }
    public int End => Start + Delta;
    public int Delta { get; private set; }

    //…

}

//класс слова для отображения в таблицах
public class TFIDFWord : ITFIDFWord
{
    private readonly IWord _currentWord;

    public int TermFrequency { get; private set; }
    public double InverseDocumentFrequency { get; private set; }
    public double TFIDF { get; private set; }
    public string Value => _currentWord.Value;
    public int OrderNumber => _currentWord.OrderNumbers.First();

    //!!! вот эта коллекция отображается во второй таблице
    public List<IWordPosition> Positions { get; private set; }

    //…

 }
```

Тогда в форме нужно создать два поля

```
//источники данных для таблиц
private BindingSource _bsWords = new BindingSource();
private BindingSource _bsWord = new BindingSource();
```

А в конструкторе формы сделать соответствующие привязки

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //привязки у таблицы слов
    _bsWords.DataSource = typeof(ITFIDFWord);
    _dataGridViewWords.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    _dataGridViewWords.DataSource = _bsWords;
    _columnWordsNumber.DataPropertyName = nameof(ITFIDFWord.OrderNumber);
    _columnWordsValue.DataPropertyName = nameof(ITFIDFWord.Value);
    _columnWordsTF.DataPropertyName = nameof(ITFIDFWord.TermFrequency);
    _columnWordsIDF.DataPropertyName = nameof(ITFIDFWord.InverseDocumentFrequency);
    _columnWordsTFIDF.DataPropertyName = nameof(ITFIDFWord.TFIDF);

    //привязки у таблицы позиций слова
    _bsWord.DataSource = _bsWords;
    _bsWord.DataMember = nameof(ITFIDFWord.Positions);
    _dataGridViewWord.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    _dataGridViewWord.DataSource = _bsWord;
    _columnWordStart.DataPropertyName = nameof(IWordPosition.Start);
    _columnWordEnd.DataPropertyName = nameof(IWordPosition.End);
    _columnWordDelta.DataPropertyName = nameof(IWordPosition.Delta);
}
```

Пример целиком [здесь.](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples/tree/master/WinFormsWords)